# Why an infinite while loop blocks the content above?

Tags: javascript

I know an infinite loop blocks the content below it but why does it block the content above the `<script>` tag?

This is the code:

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

<script type="text/javascript">
while (true) {}
</script>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser doesn't repaint the DOM after every node is parsed. That would be inefficient. It only runs an update periodically.

The while loop blocks everything, including those periodic updates.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Quentin explains the blocking behaviour.

Consider these two sets of code:

```
Message 1
<script>
function loopForever() {while (true) {}; }
setTimeout(loopForever,1);//a wait time of 0 forces a repaint on Chrome and Edge but not on Firefox
</script>

Message 2
```

2. 

```
Message 1
<script>
function loopForever() {while (true) {}; }
loopForever();
</script>
Message 2
```

In the first Message 1 and Message 2 both appear on the screen before the fan whirls and  you are in an infinite loop. In the second no messages appear, you go straight to the infinite loop with none of the DOM showing.